# How to insert node in sorted doubly linked list at the end?

Tags: c++, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};
Node* head;

void display(){
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void insert(int value){
    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = value;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(head==NULL){
        head = temp;

    }
    else{
        Node* t = head;
        while(t->next!=NULL){
            t = t->next;
        }
        t->next = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = t;
    }
}
void insertAtFirst(int value){
    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = value;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = head;
    head->prev = temp;
    head = temp;
}
void sortedInsert(int value){
    Node* curr = head;
    while(curr->next!=NULL)
        curr = curr->next;

    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = value;
    
    if(head==NULL || temp->data < head->data){
        temp->prev = NULL;
        temp->next = head;
        head->prev = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
    else if(head->next!= NULL && temp->data >= head->data){
        Node* pred = head;
        while(temp->data > pred->data){
            pred = pred->next;
        }
        
        pred->prev->next = temp;
        temp->prev = pred->prev;
        temp->next = pred;
        pred->prev = temp;
    }

    else if(curr->next==NULL){
        curr->next = temp;
        temp->prev = curr;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
}
int main()
{
    insert(10);
    insert(20);
    insert(25);
    insert(35);
    insertAtFirst(1);
    insertAtFirst(29);
    sortedInsert(30);
    sortedInsert(40);

    //1 10 20 25 29 30 35 40
    display();


    return 0;
}
```

I think I have implemented the doubly linked list probably. However, the problem I am facing is that when I try to input a node that has a greater data than the existing data of the last node, it doesn't save. There is probably something wrong with the logic I have employed - looked up some previous answers but failed to fix the problem.

Comment: What happens if `if(curr->next==NULL)` is false? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Can't be, `curr` is the last node in the list.

Comment: Why on earth would you call the last element `curr`, if the condition can never be false why is it there?

Comment: @AlanBirtles - I guess I only wanted curr to point at a node whose curr->next points to NULL, so that I can simply link temp to curr->next. I don' understand why this is not working. The logic seems okay to me.

Comment: your `while (temp->data > pred->data)` loop doesn't check for null. Have you tried using a debugger to find out where your logic goes wrong?

Comment: @AlanBirtles - I didn't want it to cheek for NULL. In  my first else if statement, I wanted to go to the next node that has higher value than temp, but I believe that the while loop inside first else if statement can find and point to NULL as it's possible that the last node can contain greater value than temp, so as per logic, pred will move to pred->next - which would be NULL.

Unfortunately I don't know how to use a debugger to find flaws.

Comment: Learning to debug is almost more important than learning to program, see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for a starting point

Comment: @AlanBirtles - thanks for the link. I will definitely look into it. Could you state what's wrong with my code? I have been trying to fix it for long already.

Comment: Visually the things I've pointed out are likely candidates for your issue, I haven't debugged your code

Answer (score 0):

As you try to insert sorted elements in your linked list, you cannot avoid using pointer of pointers in order to keep trace of the current and previous element.

Consider the following function:

```
void sortedInsert(int value) 
{
    Node **curr = nullptr;
    Node **prev = nullptr;

    int cc = 0;
    
    for (curr = &head;
        *curr && ((cc = ((*curr)->data < value)));
         prev=curr, curr = &(*curr)->next);

    Node* newElem = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newElem->data = value;
    newElem->next = *curr;
    newElem->prev = *prev;
    *curr = newElem;
}
```

Try to draw a diagram of your elements with their address...it helps a lot to understand how pointers and super-pointers work.

Z.

Comment: I believe I understand the concepts very well. The problem is with implementation. My logic is flawed in my code. Yours works just fine, but could you explain 

`for (curr = &head; *curr && ((cc = ((*curr)->data < value))); prev=curr, curr = &(*curr)->next);`

Comment: Even if your element has a `prev` member, when you reach the end of the list, the curr pointer equal `NULL`.
As you create a new element, you cannot set the `prev` member...because `curr` is null.
Using a `Node **`pointer allows you to access a Node  from the `next` field of a previous element.